# Android deeplinks not working properly

Tags: android, intentfilter, deep-linking

I have to activities that i need to deep-link them to two URLS, but every time i click a URL it shows the two activities at the same time, so How can i set the `intent-filter` to only 1 specific URL ?

1st URL `http://www.sample.com/newcars/models/33`

and its activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.NewCarModelEngineActivity"
        android:label="@string/newCars"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="sample.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/newcars/engines/"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.sample.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/newcars/engines/"
                android:scheme="http"/>

            <data
                android:host="newengine"
                android:pathPattern="/..*/..*/..*"
                android:scheme="sample"></data>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

2nd URL `http://www.sample.com/usedcars/engines/9876543`
and its activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.UsedCarEngineDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/usedCars"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="sample.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/usedcars/engines/"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.sample.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/usedcars/engines/"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="usedengine"
                android:pathPattern="/..*/..*/..*"
                android:scheme="sample"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `scheme="sample"` data in a separate intent filter. It seems like a bug, but sometimes Android just ignores the path prefix when another is present and empty or with wildcards.

You can also use `host="*sample.com"` to match both `sample.com` and `www.sample.com`.

Ex for your first activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.NewCarModelEngineActivity"
    android:label="@string/newCars"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="*sample.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/newcars/engines/" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:scheme="sample"
            android:host="newengine"
            android:pathPattern="/..*/..*/..*" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: I just tried that and It didn't work, It still shows both activities.